# Ubuntu configure Postfix mail server encoding to support IDN (internationalized domain names)

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, encoding, virtualmin

To my understanding the default **mail server** on **Ubuntu** is **Postfix**.

I have **Virtualmin** and **Webmin** installed on my Ubuntu installation. I'm trying to figure out where to **configure encoding** for sending and receiving emails to handle **IDN** in the **email address**.

I read somewhere that you can get this to work by changing the **encoding** on Postfix to **SMTPUTF8** or **IDNA** encoding. Is it possible? If so, how do I change this configuration?

Example of an IDN domain name: 日本語.idn.icann.org.

**NOTE: Special characters used in domain name... browsers have built-in support to deal with this. I want to achieve something similar for email addresses for both sending and receiving emails.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix has `SMTPUTF8` enabled by default. See [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html).

Answer (score 2):

IDN is handled entirely by the client.
No configuration change is needed in server components like Postfix to support it.
See for example the [Wikipedia article on IDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) for an explanation.